# How to keep audio [mp3 player] playing in chrome after popup closes?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

So im building a chrome extension and I have placed an audio flash player that plays a radio station. It works while the popup is open but stops after popup closes. Is it possible to keep the audio player streaming after the popup closes? If so can you give me some idea on how to achieve this? Thanks

**Edit @Serg**
I think I already have it in a background page? My setup is as follows. In my `popup.html` I have a navigation bar that links to individual html pages. To get to these the links are targeted at an iframe.

snippet from `popup.html`

```
 <div class="nav-bar">
            <a href="latest.html" target="frame" style="color:#FFF"><li class="nav">Latest</li></a>
            <a href="podcasts.html" target="frame" style="color:#FFF"><li class="nav">Podcasts</li></a>
            <a href="books.html" target="frame" style="color:#FFF"><li class="nav">Books</li></a>
            <a href="stream.html" target="frame" style="color:#FFF"><li class="nav">Radio Stream</li></a>
</div>

        <iframe src="latest.html" scrolling="auto" width="480" height="330" style="border:0px;" name="frame"></iframe>
```

snippet from `stream.html`

```
<div id="player" style="float:right;width:480px;margin:0;padding:0"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var so = new SWFObject('http://www.radiostation.com/embed/minipro.swf','fmp256','480','70','9');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','false');
so.addParam('wmode','transparent');
//so.addParam('flashvars','playlistsize=40&playlist=bottom&file=http://www.radiostation.com/feed.xml');
so.write('player');
</script>
```

Can you help me understand what you mean by placing it in a background page? How would I go about doing it?

**Edit2 @Serg** I made an attempt at putting it into the background page but im not sure how to do it properly and then call it on the `stream.html`.

Snippet from `background.html`

```
function getPlayerStream(){
                var so = new SWFObject('http://www.site.com/embed/minipro.swf','fmp256','480','70','9');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','false');
so.addParam('wmode','transparent');
//so.addParam('flashvars','playlistsize=40&playlist=bottom&file=http://www.site.com/feed.xml');
so.write('player');
            }
```

`stream.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/embed/swfobject.js"></script> 
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script type="text/javascript">
             background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
             background.getPlayerStream();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="content">


        <div id="player" style="float:right;width:480px;margin:0;padding:0">The live feed player is currently offline.</div> 

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed your player into a background page.

Background page is a unique page that isn't visible but always loaded. You can read about it [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/background_pages.html).

What you currently have in `stream.html` needs to be in a background page, if you want it to stay always loaded.

**UPDATE**

Your actual `<div id="player">` needs to be in a background page. You won't be able to actually see the player in an iframe, only programmatically control it through javascript (if that radio player supports such option).

Comment: I think I understand. please see edit2. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Jonny See the update. You won't be able to show the actual player to a user if it is in a background page.